# Storing NMA App ID, App Code & License Key in own db instead of hardcoding values in AppDelegate

Tags: here-api

We had a horror story back in August where our Here Maps SDK License Key was mistakenly changed on us (to this day, nobody still knows who did it and why). It was a nightmare, because all our users' apps froze upon launch and we had to push an update to the app store (and although I've had Apple approve an app update in the past in as little as 4 hours, that time it took them 4 days!!!).

It would make much more sense to store the values locally and then have the info populated into the app. Problem is that Here Maps requires the info in App Delegate which is the top level of app and it's difficult to build database queries in there.

Our license will be renewing soon, so I am thinking of solving this issue once and for all. Anybody had this issue before and has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We believe it would be the correct solutions to avoid major incidents.Maintaining credentials in more controlled DB is a right approach instead of keeping in AppDelegates.